# How can I verify that a PSU is operating within spec after a major component failure?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

**The PSU in question is a FSP Aurum CM 550W that is still under warranty for another 3 years.**

Tonight I experienced a major failure (possibly or extremely likely, fire was involved given how the filtering capacitors are partially black) with a Dell Optiplex 745 motherboard. A ceramic capacitor shorted to ground in phase 1 of the CPU VRM. Here is a picture showing the extent of the damage.
[[image: ]Burnt motherboard CPU VRM[1]]

Now, why it failed is something I am not currently concerned about. What I am really concerned about is whether or not I can trust this PSU in another computer. For all I know, the PSU could have been responsible for this major failure, or perhaps, the failure damaged the PSU in some way. Before I use this PSU in another computer, I'd like to make sure that it is still working correctly. Therefore, I'm wondering how I can verify that a PSU is still operating within spec.

Comment: Check the output volt of the PSU with multi meter.

Comment: @vembutech - Output voltage depends load the system is under.

Comment: The only way to be certain, with a reasonable amount of certainity, would be to replace the components around the damage and verify functionality with a schematic.

Comment: But what if the ripple voltage is not within spec? And what about it's efficiency (it could have degraded)? A multi meter can't tell you this.

Comment: @Ramhound - In this case system load is not concerned. The user wan't to check whether high voltage from PSU damaged his Mother Board.

Comment: Under warranty? Why question, just have it replaced.

Comment: @ivanivan I actually think your right about this. The actual symptom of the problem was an orange flashing power button light which, for most Dell systems, usually indicates a bad PSU but it can sometimes indicate that the motherboard has failed. Given the age of the motherboard, I automatically suspected the motherboard had failed in the CPU VRM area but after I started to desolder some of the components in the affected area (to get a better look at the damage), I have concluded that the motherboard probably still would have been able to work, even with this amount of damage to it.